# Understanding 〜たら良いか〜

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

The sentence `何と言ったら良いか分かりません` means "I don't know what I should say."

But what is the literal translation of this sentence? What is the purpose of the `か` in `良いか`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can think of it like:

> What would be right to say? I don't know

何と言ったら良いか分かりません

What  to say... / good? / I don't know

the か would supply the question mark in my literal translation above.

Comment: 言ったら is in ~tara form, (if conditional, if I say), so how would it be interpreted that way?

Comment: I had wrote "to say" by itself, but I did not mean it to represent an equivalent of the infinitive form "to say" which would correspond to 言う in japanese. I meant it like a question one asks oneself: "What to say? what to say? I don't know..." So another literal translation would be "What should I say/ good?/ I don't know"

Comment: I would say a good 'literal' translation of 言ったら is "if I said" ... giving us: 何と(what)言ったら(if I said)良いか([would be] good?)わかりません(I don't know)

Comment: @rintaun: agreed but it would probably be safer to say:
 何と(what)言ったら(if I say)良いか([would be] good?)わかりません(I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

か indicates a question. In English, questions in the main clause will be indicated by inverting the auxiliary before the clause. The addition of か in Japanese corresponds to that, but in Japanese, か is added regardless of main or embedded clause.