# Conditional Form ~たら

Tags: meaning, usage, conditionals

I've been texting with some friends and I asked:

> どんな音楽が大抵聞きますか。

He replied:

> 音楽は...なんて言ったら良いのか笑

So what exactly does the ~ったら　mean? I've gathered it might mean something like 'if I say...'

Some examples of using this form would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5324/9831

Comment: As for the first sentence, it's better to ask like : 大体｛だいたい｝/普段｛ふだん｝どんな音楽｛おんがく｝を聴｛き｝きますか？

Answer (score 3):

You're right! Generally XたらY means "if X then Y."

In this case, ...たら良い literally means "If... then (things will be good)" so なんて言ったら良いのか means "Oh, what should I say (in order for the situation to be good)" or more naturally "How should I put this."

In the same sense, どうしたらいいのか分からない means I don't know what I should do (= I don't know the thing that, if I do it, things will be good).

Answer (score 0):

Normally 'たら' means 'if'.( conditional form)
It can be used with ' もし' as well.

Eg: *もし*私はロボットが持って**いたら**せんたくがべんりになるだろう。
(if i had a robot, cleanings would be easy)